# How to make multiple vectors in c++

Tags: c++, stl

Brief :-

How to make multiple vectors ? 
We generally make vectors using - `vector<int> vector_name;` 
But any method to make multiple vectors at once ?

Comment: You know you can create a vector of vectors? The type is then called `vector<vector<int>>` (Or use any other container, of course)

Comment: You can do `std::vector<std::vector<int>> my2dVector;` With that said it's unclear exactly what you want and why you want to create multiple vectors at once. You may want to use some type of map of vectors to map a string name to a vector.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that you're trying to create multiple `vector` at once and **store them**. You can use a simple for loop, or use a **vector of vectors!**
For example:

```cpp
#include <vector>

// Using a for loop
//#define VECTOR_COUNT 5 (EDIT)
constexpr int VECTOR_COUNT = 5;
std::vector<int> myFiveVectors[VECTOR_COUNT];
for(int i = 0; i < VECTOR_COUNT; i++)
    myFiveVectors[i] = {1, 2, 3};

// Using vector of vectors
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVectors{};
myVectors.push_back({1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: Only use macros if you really need to. `#define VECTOR_COUNT 5` can be expressed using a `const` or `constexpr`.

Comment: You do really create a C-Style array of ````std::vector````? At: T.Y.M.SAI. Never ever do something like that!

Comment: @t.niese Yeah, I agree, didn't care that much as I was demonstrating the way. I think `constexpr` would be better, edited :)

Comment: so we need to use vector of vectors right ?